# C# memberwise clone on list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, clone

I have 2 class in c# :

```
 public class Item
 { 
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public List<SubItem> SubItems { get; set; }

   public Item DeepClone()
   {
     Item item = this.MemberwiseClone();
     item.SubItems = this.SubItems.Select(i => i.DeepClone()).ToList();
     return item;
   }
 }

 public class SubItem
 { 
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public SubItem DeepClone()
   {
     SubItem subItem = this.MemberwiseClone();
     return subItem;
   }
 }
```

When i call DeepClone function on *Item* class object, it clones all the members except *SubItems list*. When i access the subItems list through cloned object it threws an exception

> The entity wrapper stored in the proxy does not reference the same proxy.

What i am doing wrong here ??

Comment: Don't use the shallow MemberwiseClone() when you want a deep clone.  Try Item item = new Item() { Id = this.Id, Name = this.Name };

Comment: If you contain those items in a `List<Item>` for example you can even do `yourItemList.ToList()`, it will generate a new list from your objects.